# Is it out of place in this situation to speak up to get what I want?

Tags: professionalism, management, communication, colleagues

I currently share an office with a very abrasive and downright annoying coworker who is in the process of being relocated to another department. This means that the office her and I occupy will be reduce from an occupancy of 2 to an occupancy of 1. This is an amazing breakthrough for me because at first I THOUGHT I was going to have the office to myself.

I've heard from an anonymous source that my boss(who is female) is contemplating the act of moving one of the A/V guys out from the open lobby area and putting him in this vacancy place. So, I'd basically be trading this woman for another co-worker from the same department. When I learned this I was literally dumbstruck. However, right now I can't confirm this.

I'm not going to lie, the thought of sharing an office or being "roommates" with someone in an office as everyone in my department puts it makes me feel like a 12 year old. My job is classified as a professional position and I work with other professionals in IT and in my own department to be able to perform my role. I don't really think it's right that I shouldn't get to have a say in what happens to the office when a "seat" is left vacant.

The biggest challenge I anticipate facing with this issue is looking like a greedy, entitled whiny kid by speaking up for what I feel like I should have in my work environment to enable me to be more efficient at my job. My boss knows how to handle these things so as to avoid me being able to directly go over her head and say "I brought this issue to her and she said she didn't care and told me to deal with it".

At ths risk of sounding misogynstic my department is filled with women who by the virtue of their age and gender commonalities have already received much better treatment and accommodation than I will receive now(I'm the only male in the department, I'm 23, and everyone else is 50+). Everyone has their own office, or if they didn't, they got it. One person in the department even got a raise because of a "job reclassification" because my boss just created more work for her. But I can't even feel like I should be able to ask to keep the office to myself? Or if I do ask it's like my opinion wouldn't even matter. I've nearly been here for a year and yet the environment doesn't exactly inspire much confidence and there's always a big age disconnect between me and my boss that will linger when I have an opinion because "I'm just a kid".

Should I just deal with it? Or if this comes to pass should I speak up? I don't have the experience right now to be able to comfortably know which path to take because on one hand I know that my boss is the type of person to make my life hell over some small disagreement and on that same hand she is also the passive aggressive type who files things away when they in any way inconvenience her(whether it be manifest in some physical or emotional way). The more and more I confront her about things which she doesn't agree with would just be more and more ways in which she can twist her perception of me as some whiny youngster.

I know it's just an office but the way I see it this where I come to work every day.

Comment: You do sound misogynistic, I would wager at 23 those women didn't have private offices either.

Comment: "The biggest challenge I anticipate facing with this issue is looking like a greedy, entitled whiny kid". Hmm.

Comment: "One person in the department even got a raise because of a "job reclassification" because my boss just created more work for her." Why do you find this wrong? This is how most people get significant raises. You need to learn to do the same thing if you want a raise higher than the standard 2-3%.

Comment: Come on, which one of you guys is trying to troll us? This reads like satire on some of the questions here.

Comment: "... I don't really think it's right that I shouldn't get to have a say in what happens to the office when a "seat" is left vacant ..." Do you pay the rent for the office space? If not, stifle it. And these are the better angels of my nature doing the talking :)

Comment: So somebody works in the lobby, i.e. has no office at all, and you want an office only for yourself on the basis that your previous coworker has moved out? What makes you better that the A/V guy?

Comment: You do sound like a 12-year old.

Answer (score 28):

It is not unreasonable to replace a vacant space with another person. A junior person is generally not entitled to private space, get used to it. No, the other people near that space are virtually never consulted. She is getting the guy out of a lobby space, it is entirely reasonable and the chances of that changing given his current really bad work conditions are extremely low.

Everyone wants a private office, be grateful you only have to share with one person and that you have walls. Many people in cubicleland would be thrilled with those working conditions.